# Vue app not working with production build but works well with development

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am making an application and what I found is, my web app is working fine when I am using https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js (Development Version) but not working with https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js (Production Version).

Error:

```
You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

How Can I get this issue resolved?

Comment: Well, typically you need to (1.) find the error and then (2.) fix it.

Comment: @FK82 I am new with VueJS, can you help me out?

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, you didn't provide any details on the error and what you already tried to fix it. It's impossible to help you at this point.

Comment: @FK82 I am sorry, updated it.

Comment: Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Comment: @BillalBegueradj where to put this?

Comment: Go to that file called main.js and write that line before you instance Vue (before new Vue ..something)

Comment: @BillalBegueradj Now it's showing these errors:

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property or method "date" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>)

Comment: Have you had a look at the [suggested link](https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html) already?

Comment: @FK82 Yes, that's my whole question. When i tried using production build, my app was not working.

Comment: @AviThour Ok, I see! Keep in mind that it's considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask for debugging help. Your question will likely be closed. Try to google the exact error message or its first 20 or so characters. You'll very likely find something helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error since you have not set production mode for your project. I guess this is first time you build webapp.

Assume that you are using node + vue + npm.

Here is solution:

1. you should have something like `config` folder to have dev.js and production.js for example.
2. then you will pick what file u will using base on `process.env.NODE_ENV`. `NODE_ENV`  is a variable that u pass on your script at package.json or your terminal.
3. In production.js you have to set `mode: 'production'`
4. Whenever use deploy by CI(pipeline) or manually. You should run the script maybe like this `build:production: node YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT NODE_ENV=production`

note: YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT maybe webpack or any script that you need to build your app.

Ref: [Production mode in vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html)